# FormData not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, coldfusion

I have to upload an image onto the ColdFusion server. I have used FormData for the AJAX request to pass image file. It works fine for FF and chrome but gives issues in IE and the form does not get posted. 
Is there any alternative way to do so? So that it works fine for FF, Chrome, IE8+.

```
var formData = new FormData($(obj)[0]);
var actionPage = $(obj).attr('action');
if (validForm) {
    $('.mainPage').html('<div style="padding-top:20px;" align="center"><img alt="loading" src="/rpnet/images/ajax-loader.gif" /></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: actionPage,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (returndata) {
          $('.mainPage').html(returndata);
        }
    });
}
return false;
```

This is the code I have used for posting the form.

Comment: Try setting the “Cache-Control” header with a value of “no-cache,no-store” on your server.

Comment: can you give some more details what you mean by "issues".

Comment: @Aravind Have done that, no solution.

Comment: @M.Scherzer The form posted is found empty in IE but works fine in other browsers

Comment: From memory older versions of IE don't support uploading files through AJAX a workaround used to be using a iFrames. Save yourself some pain and use a jquery plugin that falls back gracefully to iframes for older browsers like IE.
e.g. http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#code-samples

A similar question is asked here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously

Comment: Either you can use jquery plugin as mentioned by @M.Scherzer Or you can use IFrame based solution : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript